# Getting NullPointerException for repository while using custom javax validator

Tags: java, spring, validation, junit, hibernate-validator

I am working on javax validation API in Spring Boot Application. I have a User bean and i have to validate that username given in request is unique and doesn't exist into Database.

I have created custom annotation (`UniqueUser.java`) and custom Validator(`UniqueUserValidator.java`) for this requirement.

```
public class User  {
    @NotNull
    @UniqueUser
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Email
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    private String phone;
}
```

**UniqueUser.java**

```
@Target({TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueUserValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface NameMatch
{
    String message() default "User id already exists";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**UniqueUserValidator.java**

```
public class UniqueUserValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NameMatch, Object>
{
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
   
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String userName, final ConstraintValidatorContext context)
    {
        boolean isUserExist = false;
        if(userName!=null && !userName.isEmpty()) {
        Optional<Product> product = userRepository.findByUserId(userName);
           isUserExist = product.isPresent(); 
        }
        return isUserExist;
    }
}
```

I am using Spring Data JPA to write Repository class and fetch username from DB.

**UserRepository.java:**

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

@Repository
interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

Optional<User> findByUserId();
 
}
```

**ValidationConfig.java**

```
@Bean
public Validator validator (final AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory) {

    ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byProvider( HibernateValidator.class )
        .configure().constraintValidatorFactory(new SpringConstraintValidatorFactory(autowireCapableBeanFactory))
        .buildValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();

    return validator;
}
```

**UserNameValidationTest.java**

```
public class UserNameValidationTest
{

   @Autowired
   Validator validator;

    @Test
    public void whenExistingUser_thenFai()
    { 
        User user = new User();
        user.setUserName("testUSer"); //Existing user is set
        user.setPhone("12345678"); 
        user.setPassword("password123");
        user.setEmail("test@gmail.com");
 
        //Validate bean
        Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(user);
 
        //Show errors
        if (constraintViolations.size() > 0) {
            for (ConstraintViolation<User> violation : constraintViolations) {
                System.out.println(violation.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Valid Object");
        }
        
        assertsEquals(true, constraintViolations.size()>0);
    }
}
```

On executing above test class, i am getting `NullPointerException` as `userRepository` is `null` in Custom Validator class. Can someone please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Remove your `validator` method (Spring already does all of this and more out-of-the-box and make sure that your test case uses the proper configuration (impossible to tell as there is too little information about the full test being run).

Comment: @user3244519 please check the answer, hope it helps you

Answer (score -1):

This is a classic problem using Hibernate Validators when we need to inject some bean required for validation.

First of all, the reason why `userRepository` is null inside `UniqueUserValidator` is because **your UniqueUserValidator is not annotated with any of the Spring Bean annotations, so autowiring and dependency injection doesn't even happen**.

Now if you think of using *constructor based injection* of `userRepository` in  `UniqueUserValidator`, the very moment you add that, you will get error in console complaining about not finding a no-args constructor.

Error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.package.UniqueUserValidator.<init>()
...
...
```

To solve that issue you need something else. **A hibernate properties customizer. And get rid of your ValidationConfig.java.** :

```
@Component
public class ValidatorAddingCustomizer implements HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

  private final ObjectProvider<Validator> provider;

  @Autowired
  public ValidatorAddingCustomizer(ObjectProvider<Validator> provider) {
    this.provider = provider;
  }

  @Override
  public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
    Validator validator = provider.getIfUnique();
    if (validator != null) {
      hibernateProperties.put("javax.persistence.validation.factory", validator);
    }
  }

}
```

Lastly, as I mentioned, you need to modify your `UniqueUserValidator` and use constructor based injection in it , as follows:

```
public class UniqueUserValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NameMatch, String>
{
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    public UniqueUserValidator(UserRepository userRepository) {
      this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }
   
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String userName, final ConstraintValidatorContext context)
    {
        ..... // whatever logic
    }
}
```

Another thing I noticed that **in your test class, you have missed the the two class-level annotations `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and
`@SpringBootTest(classes = YourMainApplication.class)`**

I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/abhi2495/f5e84a9cf0b8b0ac8aeef40acee8be74) on this. Please have a look if you need overall picture.

Comment: Should we instantiate a UniqueUserValidator object explicitly passing UserRepository object to it? Thanks

Comment: No @dushkin . Spring takes care of instantiation.

Comment: I added the ValidatorAddingCustomizer class. I imported java.util.Map, javax.validation.Validator and org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider. Is that correct? I also modified the Validator class exactly as you showed. Notice that my problem is not when testing but when calling a REST API, I need to use a RestController annotated class and not a repository class and that I use Spring Boot 2.3.5. When I can the API I get: "HV000064: Unable to instantiate ConstraintValidator: com.ttt.bbsim.validation.TeamIdValidator". Please help :(

Comment: Have you followed my gist ? The link of which I have given above